# How to pass data from a child window to a parent window using Javascript and/or JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am trying to pass data from a child window to a parent window.

I am trying to use opener.location.href = "test.jsp?param="+param+"";

But it keeps giving me the following error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string "

I am not sure why it gives that error since opener.location.href is supposed to accept Strings.

Here is my code for the JS of the child.

```
function something(){
var param = document.getElementById("input"); //where input is a text field

var link = 'http://localhost:8080/training/TestCases/test.jsp?param='+param'';
opener.location.href = link;
window.close();
```

}

Once this works, I plan to get the parameter in my parent's jsp file through the passed parameter.

Comment: extra '' at end of link...

Answer (score 0):

```
var link = 'http://localhost:8080/training/TestCases/test.jsp?param='+param'';
```

should be

```
var link = 'http://localhost:8080/training/TestCases/test.jsp?param='+param;
```